# Issue converting from Excel formula to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to convert an Excel-sheet to a webpage using a htmlform and JavaScript. I've got the html bit down but my JavaScript math is giving me some unexpected answers...
I'm trying to convert this Excel formula:

```
=100*((G5*(G10)^2)/(G7*((1+G9)^2-1)))^(1/5)
```

or with the actual numbers instead of cell-id's:

```
=100*((25*(2.63)^2)/(44.01*((1+13)^2-1)))^(1/5)
```

(Excel returns 45.801 which is correct).

My so far best attempt at a JavaScript version of this is:

```
let var = 100*Math.pow((varG5*Math.pow(varG10,2))/(varG7*(Math.pow((1+varG9),2-1))),1/5);
```

or with numbers instead of variables:

```
let var = 100*Math.pow((25*Math.pow(2.63,2))/(44.01*(Math.pow((1+13),2-1))),1/5);
```

both JavaScript versions (with variables or straight numbers) return "77.559" and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's likely a typo, when I try the following it gets the correct answer: `100*((G5*(G10)**2)/(G7*((1+G9)**2-1)))**(1/5);`

Comment: Thanks alot, it was probably a typo. Simplified code with ** operand instead of math.pow and it started working as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the third Math.pow does 14^1 instead of (14^2) - 1

Here is the solution:

```
100 * Math.pow(((25* Math.pow(2.63, 2)) / (44.01 * (Math.pow((1+13),2)-1))), 1/5)
```

or

```
100 * ((25*(2.63)**2) / (44.01*((1+13)**2-1))) ** (1/5)
```